# ¿Cómo puedo leer los "\n" de un archivo txt en java?

Tags: java, archivo

Por ejemplo, tengo un txt parecido al siguiente:

**Nombre1, apellido1, cuenta 1**

**Nombre2, apellido2, cuenta 2**

**Nombre3, apeliido3, cuenta3**

Entra cada línea hay un salto de línea (\n) y necesito leer dichos \n mediante Java, el readLine los elimina y si uso Read no es muy fiable.

Comment: Si lo lees en modo binario?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: ¡Cómo que read no es fiable? ¿Qué problema tiene? Además, ¿de qué clase estamos hablando? ya que hay varias clases que tienen un método read. Échale un vistazo al método read de BufferedReader: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()

Comment: con el read te refieres a que usas algunas de las muchas clases hijas de Reader? cuál en particuar?

Comment: Es con el BufferedRead, utilizo el readLine() pero no almacena los \n, y digo que read() de la misma clase no me es fiable porque son archivos de más de 100 líneas los que tengo que leer

Comment: Ese método funciona con 100 líneas y con 100 millones de líneas. Si hay algo que hace bien un ordenador y un lenguaje de programación es hacer la misma cosa muchas veces. La respuesta es usar el método read(), pero te tienes que quitar de la cabeza ese rollo de fiabilidad. El método read funciona perfectamente para cualquier número de líneas.